# iframe JSON response prompt download in IE

Tags: php, json, internet-explorer, response

Have an iframe where files are uploaded, and the iframe responds with a JSON response

How is it possible to force IE not to prompt for download? Could it be done with some extra headers on the server side?

## headers

```
Array
(
    [Host] => localhost:8080
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
    [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [Accept-Language] => da,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Referer] => http://localhost:8080/da/voucher/
    [Cookie] => session=192.168.1.36; PHPSESSID=54rbqritt9dmcpt82ujq2r0lk2
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Content-Type] => multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------143822985431828
    [Content-Length] => 7762362
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the content type headers that you are sending back are valid

```
header ("Content-Type: application/json");
```

of that is giving you you grief then switch off to:

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
```

or

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```